# training file language_id.txt for Google Prediction API unusable

Tags: utf-8, google-api, google-prediction

I'm following the [Hello Prediction example](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/hello_world) of the **Google Prediction API**.

Unfortunately the training file [language_id.txt](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/language_id.txt) seems to be corrupted somehow? I tested downloading it using Google Chrome and Firefox, same result, see screenshot:

[image]

I think, therefore my tests do not work and I always get back `English 1.0` as score for the `Muy Bueno` example string.

```
  ...
  {
   "label": "English",
   "score": "1.000000"
  },
  ...
```

**Where do I get a usable language_id.txt test file from or is there anything else I can do?**

**EDIT**: My guess is, the file has not been stored in UTF-8 format on the Google server?

Comment: I also had the same experience where it predicted Muy Bueno as english. However, Muy bueno with a small b worked fine for spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is in UTF-8, but it doesn't declare an encoding, so viewing it in a browser assumes the default HTTP charset, ISO-8859-1.

I'm not sure why you're actually getting a corrupted copy (if I view it in Chrome, it appears corrupt, but saving it results in a correct UTF-8-encoded file), but perhaps you could try another mechanism to download it?

Comment: If you are able to download it in a correct format, please add it as text file to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I'd go about attaching a file to an answer, and in any case, you'd have the same content that's already on the server. One other option: you can actually override the character set when viewing it. In Chrome, open the hamburger menu, then Tools > Encoding > UTF-8 (the top choice).  That should help, if the problem you're having is with the browser.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I didn't know that option,  that's it! Changing the encoding from Western (ISO-8859-1) to Unicode (UTF-8) did the trick!